# Change default source code directory in Visual Studio Code Remote Containers

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

My project is located in /home/user1/Development/c_project.  When I configure the project to use Containers, it wants to put this project in the same location on the Docker container.

What exactly do I need to change (in devcontainer.json) to have the project be put in /tmp/c_project and not /home/user1/Development/c_project?

Comment: Did you try the `mounts` configuration property from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference#_devcontainerjson-properties? 

`"mounts": ["source=${localWorkspaceFolder},target=/tmp/c_project,type=bind,consistency=cached"]`

Comment: Thanks @MaxIvanov that worked.  I wasn't sure if it was the "workspaceFolder" or another field.